# Would it be appropriate to use a join table here

Tags: sql, database, database-design

If I wanted users to be able to post comments on content which is stored within different tables, what would be the best way to do this?

By creating an additional table for comments on each type of content. For example;

[image: Table]

Or, use one table for comments, and use multiple join tables. For example;

[image: Join Table]

Or, simply add a foreign key for each table into the comments table?

[image: Foreign]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a foreign key for each table into a single comments table.  If the comments are in the same format for each of the three, it will make things much easier for you in the long run.  It is worth mentioning that this means you will have to have nullable foreign keys in the comments table.

The first approach you described would only be used if comments for a page are different than they are for a post.  Otherwise, it is much simpler to just have one comments table.

The table in the middle would only be necessary if you want the same comment to be posted across multiple pages (which I doubt you want).  This is called a many to many relationship, but you are describing a one to many (one page, post or profile can have many comments)

Answer (score 1):

As you don't intend to have one "comments" be shared by multiple pages/posts/user_profiles the last approach is not entirely normalized. It would allow data anomalies and redundancies.

The first one is more correct and also faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally do it the first way because it is simpler. but if you end up leaning towards the second design, you don't need the "has_comments" tables. instead put a fk column in the comments table and another column that has a type_id that holds whether the comment is of type page, post etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first option is the correct approach. The second approach feels like a case of normalization for the sake of normalization. Ask yourself : "what do I get from the second approach?". The answer is to have the same comment shared among pages, posts and user_profiles. But in reality they are not really the same (you probably want to store page comments, posts comments and user profile comments separately). So you don't gain much.

Go with option number 1 with foreign keys in place. It'll save you a whole load of hassle further down the line.